# How to create a timing watchdog for method execution count protection

Tags: java, watchdog

I want to code something that would notify a listener if a count of method call have been exceeded a max value with a specified time laps.

Let's say that I would want to know if a method is called a little bit too fast within a period of sliding 30 seconds.

In this method I would notify this *watchdog* that it must increment the counter.

And I want to be able to track more than 100 call within the configured time laps.

So the watchdog would be instantiated like this : `new Watchdog(100, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, theListener);`

I don't really know how to start the coding if this kind of thing. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have well understood, you need one or several WatchDogs which tracks if a maximumNumber has been reached within a timeLapse?

I guess this fits well the Observer pattern, in which a Subject (e.g. a program) sends notifications to Observers (e.g. a WatchDog observing how the program behaves).

Here would be the program or subject being observed by Watchdogs:

```
public class Subject {
    private List<WatchDog> watchDogs = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(WatchDog watchDog) {
        watchDogs.add(watchDog);
    }

    public void execute() {
        for (WatchDog watchDog : watchDogs) {
            watchDog.update();
        }
    }
}
```

Here would be the WatchDog definition:

```
// Verifies that maxCalls is not reached between lastTimeUpdateWasCalled and
// lastTimeUpdateWasCalled + periodInSeconds
public class WatchDog {
    private Date lastTimeUpdateWasCalled = null;
    private int currentNumberOfCalls = 0;

    private int maxCalls;
    private int periodInSeconds;

    public WatchDog(int maxCalls, int periodInSeconds) {
        this.maxCalls = maxCalls;
        this.periodInSeconds = periodInSeconds;
    }

    public void update() {
        this.currentNumberOfCalls = this.currentNumberOfCalls + 1;
        Date now = new Date();

        if (lastTimeUpdateWasCalled == null) {
            this.lastTimeUpdateWasCalled = now;
            this.currentNumberOfCalls = 1;
            return;
        }

        long endOfPeriodMillis = lastTimeUpdateWasCalled.getTime() + this.periodInSeconds * 1000L;
        Date endOfPeriod = new Date(endOfPeriodMillis);

        if (now.before(endOfPeriod)) {
            this.currentNumberOfCalls = this.currentNumberOfCalls + 1;
            if (this.currentNumberOfCalls >= this.maxCalls) {
                System.out.println("Watchdog has detected that " + this.currentNumberOfCalls + " have been done within "
                        + this.periodInSeconds + " seconds");
            }
        } else {
            // reinitialization
            this.currentNumberOfCalls = 1;
            this.lastTimeUpdateWasCalled = now;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is how you could put the whole together:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Subject s1 = new Subject();
        WatchDog w = new WatchDog(2, 2);
        s1.add(w);
        s1.execute();

        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        s1.execute();
    }
}
```

More information about the observer pattern here: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for ! Thanks.